# Div takes the same height of other div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have multiple `div` tags:

The main `div` that holds the content, if the content gets bigger, the height will obviously get bigger too, but the other divs don't.

How do I make the other divs take the main div's height?

### Code

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="header">Fiction Tools</span>
    <span id="paragraph">Lots of text will be in this text box, 
    describing in great detail the awesomeness of Fiction Tools 
    and it’s capabilities. Fiction Tools is known for lots of 
    awesome things, here are a few:</span>
    <ul id="lists">
        <li>We have this awesome design made by Driptone.</li>
        <li>Did I mention, the design is awesome? Well, it is.</li>
        <li>You should be reading this in the voice of Morgan Freeman.</li>
        <li>In a galaxy, far, far away...</li>
    </ul>
    <span id="secondparagraph">Be sure to check out our latest 
    deals which can be found on our Twitter and Facebook profiles 
    for more updates! For any other updates, you can look at our 
    news feed to the right of your screen or tablet.</span>
    <br />
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 768px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
}

#first{
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 768px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px; 
    z-index:-1;
}

#second{
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 768px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    z-index: -2;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #404040;
    padding: 25px;
    top: 15px;
}

#paragraph {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}

#secondparagraph {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    display: block;
}

#lists {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Current layout]

As you see the div that holds the content gets the height, but the others don't.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting the first and second divs to appear underneath or around your content?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If the first and second div's will have the same width as the main div, both of the divs will go under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try making the height 100%:

http://jsfiddle.net/egjUZ/

```
#first{
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 768px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px; 
    z-index:-1;
    height: 100%;
}
#second{
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 768px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    z-index:-2;
    height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using jQuery like so:

```
var articleHeight = $("#container").height();
$("#first").css({'height': +articleHeight});
$("#second").css({'height': +articleHeight});
```

This may not be the most optimal way to do it, but it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal of this is to give a *stacked appearance*, you might as well wrap your content inside 'first' and 'second' div too.

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="first">
  <div id="second">
 <!-- content as before -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first solution sucked, this works as intended.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <span id="header">Fiction Tools</span>
    <span id="paragraph">Lots of text will be in this text box, describing in great detail the awesomeness of Fiction Tools and it’s capabilities. Fiction Tools is known for lots of awesome things, here are a few:</span>
    <ul id="lists">
        <li>We have this awesome design made by Driptone.</li>
        <li>Did I mention, the design is awesome? Well, it is.</li>
        <li>You should be reading this in the voice of Morgan Freeman.</li>
        <li>In a galaxy, far, far away...</li>
    </ul>
    <span id="secondparagraph">Be sure to check out our latest deals which can be found on our Twitter and Facebook profiles for more updates! For any other updates, you can look at our news feed to the right of your screen or tablet.</span>
    <br />
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main div {
    height: 100%;
}

#main, #main div {
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 768px;
}

#main span {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

#first{
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index:-1;
}

#second{
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    z-index:-2;

}

#header {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #404040;
    top: 15px;
}

#paragraph {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}

#secondparagraph {
    color: #8f8f8f;
    padding-top: 7px;
    display: block;
}

#lists {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tpcAU/2/